# r binomial distribution barplot

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I want to create a Graph like this:

[image]

I understand that the basic structure would be

```
barplot(dbinom(x=0:n,size=n, prob=P))
```

but how do I add color to specific bars and how can I add the numbers on the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The labels for the x-axis are taken from the names of the data. So you simply need to define a data vector with appropriate names:

```
n <- 10
P <- 0.3
data <- dbinom(x=0:n,size=n, prob=P)
names(data) <- 0:n
```

The colours can be passed as a vector of colour names. You can create a vector filled with `"grey"` and then just insert `"red"` for the bars that you want to have red:

```
cols <- rep("grey", n + 1)
cols[3] <- "red"
```

And finally, plot:

```
barplot(data, col = cols)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
barplot(dbinom(x=0:n,size= n, prob=p), names.arg = 0:n, col= ifelse(0:n==k,"red","grey"))
```

-> I accidentally put the details in the dbinom brackets thats why it took me this long to figure out

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to do this task easily. You just need to introduce the number of minimum and maximum success cases and its probability and R will do the work for you. Optionally, the steps of the x axis values, and the colours can be specified:

```
bar_plot_binomial_prob <- function(min.prob, 
                                   max.prob,
                                   n, 
                                   prob, 
                                   x.labels.by=1 , 
                                   color.success="coral", 
                                   color.failure="dodgerblue") {
  # Create data frame
  df = data.frame(x=0:n, y=dbinom(0:n, n, prob))
  df$group <- df$x
  
  # Create the borders for the shadowed region
  prob_X <- c(min.prob:max.prob)
  
  # Create two groups for each observation
  df$group[df$x %in% prob_X] = "color"
  df$group[!(df$x %in% prob_X)] = "no_color"
  
  # Create the plot
  bar_plot_binomial = ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = group)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity",
             col = "black") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("no_color" = "dodgerblue", "color" = "coral"), guide = "none") +
    labs(
      x = "X",
      y = "Probability"
    ) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(df$x), 
                                          max(df$x), 
                                          by = x.labels.by),1)) +
    theme_bw()
  
  return(bar_plot_binomial)
}
```

For reproducing your example, the usage would be:

`bar_plot_binomial_prob(2, 2, 10, 0.3)`

And the output you'd get:

[image: Bar plot from the binomial distribution with the success cases colored in red]

If you were interested in 2, 3, 4 or 5 successes, then you could use:

`bar_plot_binomial_prob(2, 5, 10, 0.3)`

And you'd get:

[image: Bar plot from the binomial distribution with the success cases colored in red]